# MacOS Sierra - localhost not found while using Hugo (not related to Apache)

Tags: network, dns, webserver

note this is NOT related to Apache and I'm not looking for Apache-centered answers.

I am using the Hugo static site generator to create sites and trying to test on a MacBook running Sierra.

I am able to start the server with

```
hugo server -Dw
```

And the server starts on localhost:1313, however when I try to access that URL I get a 404. 127.0.0.1:1313 works, but then all of the links fail as they try to resolve back to localhost.

I was able to access by enabling a domain name on my router (foo.home) and then I can open the main page with localhost.foo.home:1313, but all of the Hugo links still try to use localhost:1313.

So, two questions:

1. Can I change the behavior of Hugo to use 127.0.0.1? I tried changing
   the baseURL in config.toml to localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the foo.home 
   domains, but that didn't seem to do anything.
2. Or, can I change the /etc/hosts file to resolve localhost?

Right now /etc/hosts has four entries - I am wondering if I can add another entry for 127.0.0.1 localhost but there's a warning about not making changes as it will break configuration of the loopback interface.

```
127.0.0.1       localhostw
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: `localhost` is just the hostname of the IP `127.0.0.1`; they are the same thing.  The problem that I am seeing is your first link in your `etc/hosts` file - you have a trailing `w`.  It should be `localhost`

Comment: Thanks - I thought that was added by macos for some reason and that's why there's the note to not change it. Should I try renaming from localhostw to localhost? I just don't want to blow up my boot process.

Comment: Go ahead and change it.  It can't blow up your system, it can only give you the wrong address for another host.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help.Hopefully this will help someone else who has the same issue. If you post "check your /etc/hosts file and make sure 127.0.0.1 localhost is present" as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @lonstar It looks to me like there's still a problem. "localhost" resolves to both the local IP version 4 address (127.0.0.1) *and* the local IP version 6 addresses (::1 and fe80::1%lo0). Even with the typo ("localhostw"), the IPv6 addresses should still work. Unless, that is, `hugo` is for some reason failing to listen for IPv6 connections; if this is the case, you can still have trouble connecting via localhost. Try `netstat -an | grep '[.]80 '` and see if it lists listeners on the IPv6 addresses as well as IPv4.

Comment: I didn't try the request using IPv6, as the change to hosts resolved my issue after a restart. The localhostw was something i thought was there on purpose but clearly I'd munged it up at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this error was the following:

> 127.0.0.1:1313 works, but then all of the links fail as they try to resolve back to localhost.

That gave the hint - accessing via IP works but not via hostname.  Thankfully, the `/etc/hosts` file was also included for examination.  In it we see the following line (1st line):

```
127.0.0.1       localhostw
```

The trailing "w" at the end of the hostname `localhost` will cause the error.  In effect, `localhost` wasn't defined, but `localhostw` was.

Removing the "w" will solve the issue.